# Very weird laptop keyboard issue

Tags: laptop, keyboard, hp-pavilion

I have a HP Pavilion 15-n055sm, and I have the weirdest keyboard issue. Thing is, I'm not completely sure it is a keyboard issue.

What happens: The computer randomly types the number 7, in any text box. Sometimes just one number 7, then stops, then writes a couple times, and so on, basically it's randomized.
Thing is, this keeps happening in Linux Mint, and weirdly enough, in the BIOS as well (when setting the time, it also keeps pressing number 7).

What I tried:

- default BIOS settings
- reset CMOS
- turning on with and without battery
- remove most other components (wifi, just one ram stick, any sata connections, even the touchpad)
- completely removed the laptop keyboard, and when I boot Linux Mint up for example (with just the power button and the touchpad), it keeps pressing number 7 again
- used contact spray on the keyboard ribbon port, blew it out lightly with compressed air
- tried a USB wireless keyboard, same thing

I did narrow it down to the numpad key number 7, because when I manage to turn the num lock off, I just hear a beep, no number 7.

If anyone can point me to a solution, or just even a cause for this problem, I'd greatly apreciate it.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, "completely removed the laptop keyboard, and when I boot Linux Mint up for example (with just the power button and the touchpad), it keeps pressing number 7 again." precludes your comment.

Comment: Since you've shown that the issue persists with keyboard *itself* removed, and it occurs even in BIOS, it's likely a hardware issue, such as the PCB getting wet and soaking up moisture between layers, a bad (intermittent) solder joint or a bad keyboard controller chip. For those repairs, you'd need professional help. *If* an external keyboard can be used and the internal keyboard/controller disabled, you might try that.

Comment: Now that you mentioned moisture, I had a closer look at the morherboard. I found small patches of rust on some places, such as the retaining backplate of the GPU. Also, a chip labeled ITE has some residue on the traces. I suppose drying the motherboard would not do much good?

Comment: You *might* try *removing batteries and power* and then *gently* rinsing with 91% or purer alcohol (isopropanol or ethanol) parts of the board that do not have delicate parts, such as speaker or beeper, then **thoroughly** drying with gentle air stream, e.g., a fan, for a few days. The alcohol helps draw out water (and possibly sugar syrup from a drink)... however it is important to let the alcohol and any water evaporate before reinserting batteries.

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik I think I may have solved the issue. I had a closer look at the ITE chip I was talking about. I applied some solder flux on the traces that had residue, and just gently melted the solder that was on it with a fine tipped soldering iron, until the residue was gone. For now at least the keyboard seems to work fine, in the BIOS and in the OS.

Comment: That actually could be an answer -- you might add a photo of the chip *in situ*, and describe the (nontrivial!) micro-soldering technique you used to fix it.